# Error #1034 while running flash application

Tags: actionscript-3

Alright, I know that this error is occurring because of something to do with addchild() function. On frame 2. How do I know? Because when I remove the snippets of code that dynamically place an object onto the stage it works fine. The error is below and the source code for frame 2 is below the error messages.
**Error Code**

```
TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert 0 to flash.display.DisplayObject.
    at fl.motion::AnimatorBase/play()
    at fl.motion::AnimatorBase$/processCurrentFrame()
    at fl.motion::AnimatorBase/handleEnterFrame()
    at flash.display::MovieClip/nextFrame()
    at Lemonade_fla::MainTimeline/begin()[Lemonade_fla.MainTimeline::frame1:27]
TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert 0 to
```

**FRAME 2 CODE**

```
flash.display.DisplayObject.
    stop();
var guide_tut:guide = new guide();
addChild(guide_tut);
//stand.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, check);
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, check);
function check(ev : Event) : void {
    cash.text.text = cash1;
    lemons_count.text.text = lemons1;
    cups_count.text.text = cups;
    straws_count.text.text = straws;
    ice_count.text.text = ice;


}


shop_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, shopnow);
function shopnow(event:MouseEvent):void{
    nextFrame();
}
```

Comment: What is the code at frame 1 line 27?

Comment: Also what is this line? `flash.display.DisplayObject.`

Comment: There is no code on line 27 on frame 1.

Comment: try commenting out the first line

Comment: oopse the first two lines were actually part of the error essage. Just ignore those. The first line of code for frame 2 is var guide_tut:guide = new guide();

Comment: guide is a movieclip from the library. I'm trying to call it dynamically. Is that even possible if it's on frame 2? Or do you have to be on frame 1 to call objects dynamically?

Comment: Ah... Make sure you've checked "Export for actionscript" in the properties of that object, in the library.

Answer (score 0):

1) I ran your code it works fine, the only place the error could be generated is:
flash.display.DisplayObject.
should be: flash.display.DisplayObject; 
but you don't need it.

and

var guide_tut:guide = new guide();
addChild(guide_tut);

I ran it with just an empty mc, it works fine.

2) no reason to have (i know its commented out) but there never a reason to have
stand.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, check) ever since check is EnterFrame

basically you're error is within either display, most likely you're not extending the class from MovieClip

public class guide extends MovieClip

instead of movieclip it can be sprite or other displayobject...