# How can I be receving an error on frame 1 and line 23 when there is no code on that line?

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm getting an error when I click a button which brings me to frame 2. The error is:

```
Warning: No libraries were linked as Runtime Shared Libraries (RSLs) because of your publish settings: AIR Android
[SWF] Lemonade-boy.swf - 862607 bytes after decompression
TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert 0 to flash.display.DisplayObject.
    at fl.motion::AnimatorBase/play()
    at fl.motion::AnimatorBase$/processCurrentFrame()
    at fl.motion::AnimatorBase/handleEnterFrame()
    at flash.display::MovieClip/nextFrame()
    at Lemonade_fla::MainTimeline/start_now()[Lemonade_fla.MainTimeline::frame1:23]
```

The Code for Frame 1 is (If I can count correctly that is only 18 lines... not 23+):

```
//import flash.events.Event;
stop();
//var bg1_menue:Sound = new Sound();
//bg1_menue.load(new URLRequest("/bg1_menu/bg1_menu.mp3"));
//bg1_menue.play();
var cash1:Number = 5.00;
var maximum_storage:Number = 500;
var lemons1:Number = 10;
//var storage1:Number = lemons1;
var cups:Number = 10;
var straws:Number = 100;
var ice:Number = 5;
var drinks:Number = 0;

startbt.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, start_now);
function start_now(event:MouseEvent):void{
    nextFrame();
}
```

CAN SOMEONE PLEASE EXPLAIN HOW TO FIX THIS ERROR? Thank you!

Comment: pretty sure frames are zero based so post your code for the next frame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is this all the code you have? the first frame has everything listed above and there is a second frame(which should exist) which has no code in it?

EDIT: The code above works perfectly fine, you're error is coming from somewhere else.

**On the side, you shouldn't create a new thread for the same error:** 
[Tracing flash to a line which doesn't exist, flash CS5/AS3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5435753/tracing-flash-to-a-line-which-doesnt-exist-flash-cs5-as3) 
[Error #1034 while running flash application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5434954/error-1034-while-running-flash-application)

just put the entire question in one thread, or people will be discouraged from answering.